# EventReceiver is working on local site where code is written.But when I deploy its wsp on another site it is not working?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I have written Event Receiver for a list on my local site on its item added event in that event receiver it creates subsite under a top level site. And updates a url in the list. This functionality is working fine on my own development machine but when i deployed wsp to another machine it is not working why does that happen so? Even I can't debug that wsp, what is the way to find out error?

Answer (score -1):

Configure ULS Logs and try to find events relative to your solution.

http://samirvaidya.blogspot.ru/2012/03/where-are-sharepoint-uls-logs.html
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463595(v=office.15).aspx